# MVC Match Object to API expecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to Serialize this model to the model that the API is expecting. The FirstName and LastName is fine but the IntendedUse object is not matching.  I also need it to work with in the View so I am not sure how to correct the model to match the API. Any help would be great.

API is expecting data in this form

```
{
    "FirstName": "1",
    "LastName": "1",
    "SelectedProjectMaterial":
    [
        {   
            "IntendedUse":{
                "Value":47
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Current Output from Serialize the Object

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

{"FirstName":"1",
 "LastName":"1",
  selectedIntendedUseId":{"Name":null,"Value":47,},
}
```

Model

```
[Display(Name = "* First Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
[Required]
public GenericValues selectedIntendedUseId { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div>* Intended Use</div>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(
   x => x.selectedIntendedUseId.Value,
   new SelectList(Model.ListOfIntendedUses, "Value", "Name"),
   "-- please select a Intended Use--",
   new { id = "ddlUses", @class = "form-control" }
   )
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.selectedIntendedUseId.Value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Dto (View Model) Instead of using domain model direct as below

Model

```
public class ModelDto{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int selectedIntendedUseId { get; set; }
}
```

and receive this model from your action method or whatever
So your view will be like

```
@model ModelDto
<div>* Intended Use</div>
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedIntendedUseId,
new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfIntendedUses, "Value", "Name"),
"-- please select a Intended Use--",
new { id = "ddlUses", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.selectedIntendedUseId.Value)
```

and your controller will be like
Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ControllerAction()
{
ViewBag.ListOfIntendedUses = //Select From DB or whatever
return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ControllerAction(ModelDto model)
{
model.selectedIntendedUseId = //you will get id here, use it for your logic
return View();
}
```

hope it's clear now

sample ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ControllerName/ActionMethodName",
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: How will this fix the problem? Please explain more

Comment: Thanks so what do you do about the model for the api? You need to send JSON to the server ? Do you convert ModelDto into APIModelDto? And how would you get it into that format?

Comment: So when the form post from the view the model that will be sent will me Modeldto will that be converted

Comment: you will specify content type to be application/json and do JSON.stringify for form data like sample ajax call in updated answer